# How do you handle a coworker who does not know how to work in a team?

Tags: professionalism, management, work-environment, manager

I've been seven months in a small company of thirty people, I work with another guy, who also happens to be one of the first employees of the company, in the same project.

This guy does not use the internal tools that we use for collaboration, does not reply when asked in these tools, during meetings he is very unclear about what he is working on and just changes topic, sometimes he doesn't even attend meetings.

He does not pull his weight nor delegate responsibilities, many tasks just remain blocked waiting for him to answer, he does not share project and customer information he obtains during meetings with his boss. The only time he works is when something urgent comes from his boss, by that time he mostly takes what I've done, modifies it, makes it worse and just delivers it.

For me, this is becoming a problem in terms of managing expectations with my boss and peers, as what we are delivering is garbage in terms of quality.

So far what I've done with my coworker is:

- Let him fall by his own weight; we've sent incomplete deliverables because of him and lost potential customers. I have not stepped in to complete his tasks nor will I.
- I told him about these issues and he replied he was sorry and that he will try to use the internal tools, he also mentioned that he is available for a chat when needed, I told him it is not my job to chase him for answers as the norm.
- For the tasks that he was blocking me in, I started to just deliver them, he just blocked me from completing tasks without his approval. His approval can take from two weeks to more than a month usually. This is insanely slow for the industry I work in.
- I told the guy responsible for planning tasks of the low throughput that I have, and he told me he would speak with my coworker. My coworker then came to me infuriated saying that he is available for a chat if there is something I need to tell him and that there is no need to involve others. This confirmed to me he wants to control the communication flow.

He behaves like this with everyone in the company, I just happen to work in the same project as him and I am more exposed to this.

At the end of the day, this is a problem for the company. For me, it is one of the most relaxed jobs I've had because basically I am not allowed to do much, but I wonder for how long, given what we are doing is trash and we are losing customers.

I was wondering how have you handled a similar situation in the past as a subordinate, and what would you expect me to do as your subordinate if you were my manager?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142337/discussion-on-question-by-milten-how-do-you-handle-a-coworker-who-does-not-know).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're working with someone who doesn't appear to be pulling their weight, you first go to them (as you have), tell them what you need, and ask if that is something they can provide.

If they stonewall you, don't communicate, or don't provide what you need, the next step is to go to your manager.  Tell them what you think you need, what you see the problem is when you don't get it, and ask if they have suggestions for how you can change your workflow to provide what you think your output should be.

This is not saying that the other person is not doing their job.  And it's leaving it open to the possibility that what you are doing is not what you need to be doing.  But if your manager wants you to do A, and you need the co-worker to provide B before you can finish A, and the manager agrees with that, you've made it clear that you're not getting B, and the manager needs to step in and help you get that.

There are several potential outcomes:

- Manager says to wait until you get B.  You wait.  Manager asks why A is late.  You point out that you are still waiting for B, as manager requested.
- Manager talks to co-worker and co-worker starts responding.  (You might need to go to manager each time.)
- Manager abdicates their own responsibility and tells you to figure it out.  (You likely won't be able to win.)
- Manager tells you that you're actually solving the wrong problem, and you don't need B to finish A.  Even if you disagree, as long as that is documented, it's the manager's call.

Comment: Point 4 requires documented proof. Verbal is NOT proof. If the manager refuses to send out email, you write your own and say, "As per our verbal discussion, you stated that...." and have documented record of what is said, CCing the parties involved (manager, and coworker).

Comment: @Nelson -- very good point!  And good strategy, too.

Answer (score 30):

> we've sent incomplete deliverables because of him and lost potential customers

Brutal.

The actual root issue is that you are blocked, not that you are blocked by him. Why is he the only one who can approve? Issue is larger than just him being slow.

Raise the issue with management, but do not say "He is slow, he does not do this..., etc.". Instead say, "We need another lead/approver to help, so we can accelerate approvals, because two weeks for an approval is too slow. If that is not possible is there anything else we can do to reduce approval times?"

Stepping in to help prevent customer loss instead of letting things fail, could also eventually promote you to a position where you become this person, with approval powers.

Comment: Ah yes, I was told to add more people to review my work and I will start doing that next week, but they are people from other projects and I am not sure how they will feel about this... I also have approval powers but I can't approve my own work. I would step in to fix things and I have done that in the past in other companies, but it rarely solves the core issue, I would rather just expose it and let the people with real power deal with it.

Comment: Adding others to pull requests who are not on projects, just equals dead in the water. It needs to be an official "this-person-is-also-responsible" addition to the review process, not someone optional. We have discussions like this from time to time amongst our orgs various projects. Optional reviews have never really worked. You need to push for someone else with responsibility to review. The down side is that their reviews tend to be lesser quality - but also can result in the second reviewer pulling the primary reviewer in.

Comment: I agree with you and I do not think it is a solution, we will most likely have the same approval times, as those new people won't be invested in a project that they do not work on and probably do not have time allocated for this project either. I was hoping to use that in the future to get a new guy in the project.

Comment: That would be the best end result a new hire. Had a kinda-similar situation with a co-worker but he was not on my project, but he works on something my project has a dependency on. In the end, making physical calls was the only way to get him responsive. Ask a question in IM, no response for a few hours, start physically calling him - "Hey sent you a msg, need to get this out EOD", etc. Eventually he became really responsive in the internal chat which he was not before. Perhaps this could work - as the guy is not looking at the internal project tools?

Comment: That is the part I want to avoid which implies being his caretaker. He does not attend daily scrum meetings, nor updates Jira tickets, in sprint planning he is extremely unclear about what he is doing or what he has accomplished thus we can't plan sprints either. He expects people to contact him via Teams when in nees for updates, reviews or the like and he usually ignores these messages too. It is a known bottleneck in the company.

Comment: Problem is, he is getting special treatment, perhaps because of his early-days in the infant (assumed) company. Options I see: (1) continue as it, let things fail. Will not have a good outcome for you, (2) make it you versus him. With his favor, it may not work out for you or (3) chase him up to get things done - annoying but for the sake of the project, and a good outcome for you, an option. If you want to pursue (2) then you are going to have to combine good-data-capture, good manager communication and saving-the-day (without it, data will prove you also let it fail).

Comment: @Milten you _will_ have to do something with him. Consider that your behaviour is part of the situation, and just as you want things out of him that you don't get, he may be wanting things out of you - and that's independent of whether any of these expectations are fair or not, workplace is only marginally about fairness, getting stuff done is _much_ more important.

Comment: @Milten Sounds like he does not want to be a part of your scrum pipeline (understandable, personally), is not really a part of the team, and there is some miscommunication about the expectations. That is, he might have a vision/technical know-how, but no leadership skills. Top management probably wants to integrate his input into your workflow, but currently it does so in a blocking way. You only have so much power to leverage if it is a management issue.

Answer (score 7):

The issue here is that you have no authority over this individual.

This leads you to realistically 3 courses of action:

1: Look for a new job - it's not worth your time/stress/professional reputation in the industry delivering crap products/services.

2: Malicious compliance - Go all in on the Email trail, make sure that the boundaries are clearly demarcated between whose responsible for what - and when the inevitable happens and there's a failure of sufficient epicness that fingers start getting points and blame starts being handed out - you have the receipts to show who was at fault and let them face the consequences.

Note - although Malicious Compliance has an air of karmic justice to it - and sometimes can be very satisfying - it's not the best course of action.

3: "A Castle avoided ceases to be an obstacle" - If he is holding things up and causing substandard delivery - try and find ways to work around him. Perhaps taking things up with the Owner when he doesn't respond - but even then, this can be difficult to do if the organizational structure doesn't allow this - but you can do quite a bit.

Realistically though - this is an issue that the company owner needs to decide if it's worth *his company* to keep this person in such a position where they keep delivering substandard product.

Comment: I agree, right now I am doing three as much as possible and being quite explicit about the situation and delays. I do not want to get involved much because in my  experience it is better to have authority over people with this mindset rather than trusting on their good intentions, and I do not have it

Answer (score 1):

I'll address what you are doing.

- Let him fall by his own weight; we've sent incomplete deliverables because of him and lost potential customers. I have not stepped in to complete his tasks nor will I.

If you want to be a good employee, your job is to make the companies goals succeed.  If someone isn't doing something and it is needed to deliver something and it is the best thing for the company, you do it.

This reads like resentment.  Resentment is, to be frank, your problem.  If you are letting customers be lost and bad quality or incomplete stuff to be shipped because you resent a coworker, the companies problems include you.

- I told him about these issues and he replied he was sorry and that he will try to use the internal tools, he also mentioned that he is available for a chat when needed, I told him it is not my job to chase him for answers as the norm.

If there is something you need to get done, and using a specific tool doesn't solve it, then you find another solution.  Saying "it isn't my fault the tool doesn't work -- it is because someone else isn't using it right" is an excuse.

Yes, it can suck if someone isn't using the "right" workflow.  But the goal of a company isn't people using specific internal tools, except insofar as that helps the companies other goals.  The goal is getting stuff done.

Again, this looks like resentment.  You resent having to bother him to get work done.  Feel free to resent the person -- but that doesn't mean you get a by on getting work done.

- For the tasks that he was blocking me in, I started to just deliver them, he just blocked me from completing tasks without his approval. His approval can take from two weeks to more than a month usually. This is insanely slow for the industry I work in.

This is a reasonable step.  The next thing is, if the task is urgent, is to work out how to get approval done faster.  Or get a way to do it without approval if approval isn't adding value.

This might require spending effort talking with the person, which might not be something you want to do.  But if the task is urgent, then that should be your priority.  If it isn't, then it can wait.

You can document how hard it is to get approval and mention this to *your* manager, saying it is a roadblock on your productivity, or how long it takes to get approval being a problem.  You should first bring this up with the person witholding approval to see if there is a way to do it faster.

- I told the guy responsible for planning tasks of the low throughput that I have, and he told me he would speak with my coworker. My coworker then came to me infuriated saying that he is available for a chat if there is something I need to tell him and that there is no need to involve others. This confirmed to me he wants to control the communication flow.

Yes, you should first talk to him about it.  Find ways to make it faster, and only if those ways to make it faster are failing raise it to the next level.  And, if it is taking a lot of effort to make it faster, you should mention that *while working on making it faster*, before raising the issue to the next level.

The goal here is to *succeed* first, not *fail in a way that isn't your fault*.

If it proves difficult to succeed - either too difficult in that despite efforts you are failing, or just a real pain to make it good enough - raise those issues with your manager.  But first, raise them with your peer in a non-confrontational way, possibly repeatedly.

- Communicate with your peer outside "standard" channels.  Possibly including pinging that the "standard" channel requires attention.  Do this when it is urgent, and when it isn't urgent and no action has been taken after a slight delay.

Why?  Because your goal is success, not failure-with-excuse.  One of your resources doesn't work with the standard tools?  Work around it, don't give up.

- If someone doesn't deliver a piece of a product needed, and that product has value, ask your manager for permission to finish it.  If you have latitude to pick your own tasks, just finish it yourself without asking permission.

During planning, be realistic about actual workload your resources (including this colleague) can pull off.

Why?  Because your goal is success, not failure-with-excuse.  One of your resources can't produce fast enough?  Bypass it.

- If someone is blocking you from completing tasks without their approval, get their approval.  Determine what is needed for that approval.  If what is needed isn't reasonable, say it isn't reasonable, and explain why it is urgent.  If the problem persists, talk to your manager about how the approval process results in a bottleneck, and see if there is an alternative.  This can include what value, if any, the approval gave.

Why?  Because your goal is success, not failure-with-excuse.  If a step is needlessly difficult, you don't just give up.  You put in the work required to get through the step.  And then you look for process optimization.  But first you succeed.

- Talk with the coworker first about issues.  If they aren't solved, explain they aren't solved to the coworker.  Try their solutions, and explain the problem with them if they don't work.  Any issues you raise to management shouldn't be a surprise to the coworker.

Why?  Because the goal is success, not failure-with-excuses.  The coworker is a resource and a problem.  You fix the problem and improve the resource.  The manager can only give that coworker instructions (which you are capable of doing) and discipline them (which you cannot).  Discipline is not the desired goal for the company -- they want their resources to be useful.  So attempt to solve the problem and escalate *on the specific problem that the attempt failed at*.

Then if they come back, betrayed, you can honestly say "we tried to solve it, it didn't work, so I mentioned it to my manager as an unsolved productivity problem.  We should keep at solving it.  How about Y?"

It isn't about getting the coworker in trouble, it is about solving that productivity problem.

Remember: it may be the case that the delays you are seeing exist for a reason you are unaware of.  Focus on the productivity problem, not the person causing it.

When you are managing someone, then focus on the person.  When someone asks for peer reviews, you can list the issues you have.

Comment: I can't reply to all here but I appreciate your point of view and the time it took for you to write it. I am not one to define the term "good employee" or "success" in the context of the company I work for, my goal is to meet the expectations of the company for my role to the best of my abilities and be aligned with their strategy and goals, ultimately the guy behaves like this with everyone in the company and it is known. I wouldn't be able to sustain on my own many of the things you proposed here for a long period of time and I am afraid it would just contribute to burn me out.

Answer (score 0):

All the answer I've read say something like "*Make it fail and explain that it's his fault.*", but what then? Things will have failed and nobody, including you, has stepped up to the plate to save the day. So both of you are bad employees.

Why not opt for the other attitude? "*Make it succeed and explain that it's your success.*". You'll end up being the guy who steps up to the plate, who saves the day, and you'll be a good employee (which you can later translate into salary raise, other financial reward or a promotion).

Comment: A downvote for the only constructive answer???

Comment: "All the answer I've read say something like Make it fail and explain that it's his fault." - actually none of the answers said it. "Make it succeed and explain that it's your success." - not everything can be solved by just person. I'm sure OP has already tried everything and asking here for help because it didn't help.

Comment: @Dominique there's nothing constructive about saying "make it succeed". OP is already trying to make it succeed, but they describe numerous legitimate problems which stand in the way of doing so and you've provided literally zero advice on how to fix or mitigate any of them.

Comment: "many tasks just remain blocked waiting for him to answer". Just write an answer yourself, print it, go to his desk, ask him if he agrees and if yes, send it to the customer (with your boss in copy) and the customer won't be lost. In case he disagrees, tell him to correct your proposal as a reply on the mail you'll send him (and also in that mail, you put the boss in copy).

Comment: @ChrisH actually the OP is refusing to contact the roadblock person directly, on the grounds "he is not responsible for handholding him". If he says he has a pretty low-work job due to that, there's no reason why he shouldn't take that spare time to actually help the coworker to become a better teamplayer.

Comment: Up to now: 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes. I had no idea that such a simple proposal would be so controversial :-)

Comment: I do not think it is that simple, I have faced many times a simple conclusion: "If there is no interest in changing things from the top, there is nothing one can do from the bottom", I fear evertything would be in vain and could put me on the spotlight for going against the current culture, ultimately it is beyond my responsabilities.

Comment: I think the answer is controversial because it seems to be misrepresenting what the other answers suggest

Comment: @Dominique it doesn't make any sense if a college has to do project X, and you go and do X without asking them if they'd like you to do it, and without permission from your manager.

Comment: @Jonast92: Yes, it just might! Imagine a boss, describing all tables and their column definitions, and the "bad" colleague has to create them, but doesn't. In the meantime you make a Notepad++ macro in order to turn the requests from your boss into a batchfile. The "bad" colleague, trying to do it manually, must admit not having done his job, but you can mention having created a macro and propose using it for that purpose. You save the project and you prove you're a better employee than that "bad" employee.

Comment: @Dominique You'd be going against your boss's orders and at the end of the day only proving that you can't follow instructions. Asking if you can help and doing so is one thing, doing work you're not assigned to do and you didn't ask if you could do, not so good.